# How do I correctly specify the **FROM** value to be my local image and not from a Docker Hub registry?

Tags: docker, neo4j

I want to build a new image from an existing image on my local machine. This is what my context looks like. **neo4j** is the database/image I am using.

```
neo4j
|-data
|-plugins
|-Dockerfile
```

The contents of my `Dockerfile` looks like this

```
FROM "C:\neo4j"
```

When I do `docker build .` I get the following:

```
$ docker build .
Sending build context to Docker daemon 435.2 MB
Step 1 : FROM "C:\neo4j"
Error parsing reference: "\"C:\\neo4j\"" is not a valid repository/tag
```

How do I correctly specify the **FROM** value to be my local image and not from a Docker Hub registry?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`FROM` requires the image to be in a registry (public or private) or in the local cache of your docker host.

You can however specify `FROM: scratch` which does what it says; it won't rely on any other base image. You container will only contain what your Dockerfile lists.

Also you can't reference files outside of the current dir where your Dockerfile is. This is because the whole directory that contains your Dockerfile is copied to the docker host to be built there. Create a `.dockerignore` file to list content that isn't needed to build your image. It'll speed the building since they won't be copied to the host for the build step.